# Kiosk GUI layout

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, layout, kiosk

I need to develop a GUI for a self-service kiosk. The kiosk will take food orders (i.e pizza, burgers, salads) and provide the ability to pay using a credit card. Can anyone suggest the best GUI layout or approach? I want to make it intuitive and simple. I want to minimize the number of button clicks. If you can provide examples, that would be great.Thanks for your help.

Comment: So much of this question depends on your business requirements and target market.  To answer this question, I would need to sit down w/ you and document your requirements; build some prototypes, and do some user testing in your target market and make various revisions along the way.  "Best" is very subjective.

Comment: Your other question which is very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692371/kiosk-gui-layout

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ones i prefer have the fields for the delivery details (address & dynamically generated order listing) on the right side as a small strip, the product category you're currently browsing to the left and category navigation tabs either at the top or as a thin strip in the outermost left position. No need to re-invent the wheel.
That way the user can browse, already specify the address details and always keep track of the already added order positions, modify item count and keep track of the resulting costs.

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of feedback i'm looking for.